# How can frequency of acoustic wave not change?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

I am already familiar with the notion of extra waves coming out of nowhere or waves piling up, but consider this-   A sound wave passes from a less dense to a denser medium(so speeds up) . Assuming frequency is same, the wavelength increases. Since time period is inversely related to wavelength, so it decreases. Since f=1/t, f changes.
What is happening?

Comment: The effect of density is to decrease the speed of sound.  But you cannot tell if it speeds up or slows down just from density.  The elastic properties of the medium matter too.

Comment: i am asking that is speed increase, wavelength increase, so time period decrease, so frequency increase... HOW

Comment: The period is not inversely related to wavelength. You got this wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

The frequency (not the period) is inversely related to the wavelength, so you can write
$$f = \frac{1}{T} \propto\frac{1}{\lambda},$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $T$ is the period, and $f$ is the frequency.  However, proportionality is not equality.  There may be other factors involved.  In fact, equality may be written as
$$f = \frac{1}{T} = \frac{c}{\lambda},$$
where $c$ is the wave speed.  If the frequency is held constant, which implies that the period is held constant, then changing the wave speed changes the wavelength.  You can actually use this relationship to figure out how the wavelength changes when you change wave speeds.

Incidentally, the relationship $\lambda f=c$ is true for all linear waves, where the mathematical concept of linearity is roughly equivalent to the physical concept of small amplitudes.  Thus, the above explanation works for water waves and light, as well.

Comment: i am saying that for c=fλ, if c increases, then λ increases. because T is proportional to λ directly, then T increases, decreasing F. HOW?

Comment: The period $T$ and the frequency $f$ are, by definition, the inverse of each other, without any additional constants.  If you hold $f$ or $T$ constant and change the wave speed your wavelength will change in proportion.  I updated the answer to emphasize that $T$ and $f$ give the same information.

Comment: i am trying to say that if wavelength goes down, then doesnt the time period decrease, inxcreasing frequency

Comment: No, because the wavelength goes down at the same rate as the wave speed, so the ratio $c/\lambda$ does not change.

Comment: but if we imagine it physically happening, then wavelength going down will mean that the particle has less horizontal distance on agraph to traverse...or am i confusing something with wavelength?

Comment: It does have less distance to traverse, but it is also going more slowly.  Thus the time it takes for the wave (or the peak of the wave, to be more precise) to cross the distance remains the same as if the wave speed had not changed.

Comment: like I am imagining a graph (d-d) then low wavelngth means squeezing the graph horizontally, so the distance for the particle decreases(to be covered), so it must take a less time period. Plus, even if i am wrong here(which i know is true-the partice never travels horizontally), the equation itself tells that lambda is proportional to the time period(although i cant imagine it correctly physically happening)

Comment: like if we imagine the particle vibrating, then for an individual particle. how do we identiffy wavelngth

Comment: If you are looking at a single particle oscillating in place, there is no concept of a wavelength, as it is not traveling anywhere; it isn't a wave.

Comment: i am getting too confused.

Comment: @Michael M The period is NOT inversely related to wavelength. The relationship is $\lambda=c T$ so the period is directly proportional to wavelength and vice-versa. Your formula with the inverses shows exactly the same direct proportionality.

Comment: @nasu Oops, I miswrote the first sentence.  Thank you for finding that.  I have fixed my answer.  Everything else is, I believe, correct.